# Extension Hose for a Tank Booster

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

My plumber told me that [this tank booster](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Cash-Acme-24644-Tank-Booster-Pro-w-Braided-Hose-Temperature-Gauge) won't work with my [hot water heater](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-Platinum-50-gal-10-Year-Hybrid-High-Efficiency-Smart-Tank-Electric-Water-Heater-XE50T10HD50U1/303419574).

[edited: somehow the rest of my question got stripped off on first post]

His reason is that the cold water inlet and the hot water outlet are too far apart. It appears a longer hose could be used with the booster, but he said that it can't. I suspect he's wrong and just want to confirm. I read the manual for the tank booster and it doesn't say anything about not extending the cold water hose. I read the tank manual too and it *recommends* using a mixer valve (for safety... doesn't mention boosting).

Do you think I can go ahead and install this booster and simply get a longer hose for the cold water?

Comment: The hot water heater manual actually _recommends_ the use of a mixer valve.

Comment: So what is your question? Why do you think the plumber is wrong? Why does s/he say it won't work`? what did s/he suggest?

Comment: Sorry. Somehow it doesn't appear my entire question made it. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would not work, so I'm just going to give a little background about how these 'boosters' work so you can decide for yourself.

As you shower or bathe, you open a faucet to mix hot water from the tank with cold water from the city, producing a comfortable mixture. The hotter the tank set point, the less hot water you need to draw to produce a comfortable mixture and the longer you can shower.

The tank temperature has nothing to do with this component. Even without this component, you can "boost" the amount of hot water in your house by increasing the temperature of the tank.

There are however major risks to increasing the tank temperature. Notice that it takes only 2 seconds of exposure to 60C water to produce the same amount of burn as 1 minute of exposure of 50C water.

[image]

For this reason, it is really unsafe to simply boost your hot water temperature. A baby (yours or someone else's) may come in and turn on your hot water tap. Or drunken you may do the same. This may lead to serious injuries. It is therefore against code to have high-temperature water flowing out of a tap.

The way this component (a mixing valve) "boosts" water is that it allows you to keep the tank at a high temperature but it ensures that the water coming out of the tank (and into your faucet) is mixed with cold water automatically shortly after it leaves the tank.

This "booster" is a safety feature that allows you to meet code requirements and stay safe.

Comment: Thank you. I added to my question. I do know how the booster works and am just wondering if there's any reason its cold water inlet can't be extended.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why you can't just add a longer hose.

Comment: For the record, another plumber from the same outfit confirmed that the booster could be installed and completed the operation and it works just fine.